# Asynchronously paint datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I need to paint a datagridview on a main thread. The data I'm processing comes from big excel files that often contain thousands of records. 
When I validate (check for errors and paint), it blocks the main UI, displays "application is not responding" and doesnt refresh the progress bar untill its finished.

I dont have such problem when using background worker, but since its necessary to paint datagrid && add listview items on the main thread this approach won't work.

I'm ok with it running on main thread, but I want it to show the progress bar and not become unresponsive.

I'm fairly new to asynchronous programming and Control.Invoke(). How should I handle this?

Comment: Could you not split the validation and loading into datagridview processes? That way the validation can be done in a backgroundthread. You could also load everything into your datasets in the background and then let the datagridview load that data when everything is done

Comment: That would be my approach, but its wastefull - iterating over excel file, making a list of rows with errors and then iterating again to add listviewitems and paint the grid.

Answer (score 0):

`Control.Invoke()` executes code in the main thread (exactly what you don't want).

You must use your `DataGridView` in [`VirtualMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In this mode, only visible cells are painted so you can have a lot of data in your `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Application.DoEvents() in each iteration, Invoking the painting when necessary, setting Form.DoubleBuffered to true and using this:

```
  [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);
    private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11;
```

to stop/start the painting of datagridview and eventually call refresh() at the end, effectively saving me 80% time of the validation process.

I highly recommend using backgroundWorker though.